# Remove while loop in T-SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, while-loop, temp-tables

There were some `while` loops in a procedure and I want to remove them / replace with temp tables or any other ( not cursor) .

Below I have created a dummy syntax, I have to populate the `TEMP_TABLE` table based on some calculations. Please share any better option to do the same:

```
SET @J = 0
SET @DIFFERENCE = 10
SET @INCREMENT = 2

WHILE (@J < @DIFFERENCE) 
BEGIN   
    SET @TO_DATE = (SELECT DATEADD(D, @INCREMENT, @TO_DATE))   

    IF (@TO_DATE <= GETDATE())
       INSERT INTO TEMP_TABLE 
       VALUES(@J, @TO_DATE)   

    SET @J = @J + @INCREMENT  
END
```

Comment: There are many examples on SO of using tally tables to populate date table? Did you try to search anything? The clue is to generate number range and use simple `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM (tally) ... WHERE (loop condition)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using `Tally table`

```
;WITH e1(n) AS
(
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
), -- 10
e2(n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM e1 CROSS JOIN e1 AS b), -- 10*10
e3(n) AS (SELECT 2 FROM e1 CROSS JOIN e2), -- 10*100
e4(n)  as ( SELECT n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n) FROM e3)
SELECT n,
       Dateadd(D, n, @TO_DATE)
FROM   e4
WHERE  N <= @DIFFERENCE
       AND N%@INCREMENT = 0
```

For more info on [***`Generate a set or sequence without loops`***](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)